# how to execute content_script without clicking on the plugin icon in chrome plugin?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

I want to execute my content_script without clicking on the plugin icon.

manifest.json

```js
{
  "short_name": "my plugin",
  "name": "vanilla Chrome Extension",

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "tabs", "<all_urls>", "webNavigation"],
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "my plugin"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "css": ["content-script.css"],
      " js ": ["content-script.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ]
}
```

I also try document_idel and document_start

content-script.js

```js
console.log("inside plugin script");
document.querySelectorAll("h1").style.backgroundColor = "#c1c1c1";
```

I try to find out from docs but can't figure out what to do

Comment: Replace `" js "` with `"js"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @wOxxOm commented on my question, in my manifest.json content_scripts section I leave space before and after "js" when I remove those spaces it works.